# Is it possible to change the record separator used with the SQLite Command-Line utility?

Tags: command-line, sqlite

I know it's possible to set the field separator using the `.separator` command, is it possible to do the same with the record separator? For example, to specify `0x1E` be used to separate records to match `0x1F` used for separating fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with the `-newline` option or the second parameter of `.separator`, but only for output, and only in CSV mode, and only with SQLite 3.8.6 or later.